# IE11 Dates from a text field in a variable not passing properly to a service

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

So I have a website that uses dates to search a database.  When working in Firefox and Chrome everything works just fine, but when I toss it into IE (specifically IE 11) the searching wont work.  I've narrowed down my issue to when I get the data from a text field using jquery it wont pass correctly.

Here is an example:

```
    var start= $('#startdate').val();
    var end = $('#enddate').val();
    $.post(this.url(), {start: start, end: end }, function(data) {
            // do stuff with data
    }));
```

Now what I have tried is messing around in the console and in the js file itself.  The following things work fine:

```
new Date('12/1/2016'));
new Date(Date.parse('12/1/2016')));
var start = '12/16/2016';
new Date(start ));
new Date(Date.parse(start)));
```

But as soon as I add a jquery selector into the mix it breaks and no longer works.  Has anyone encountered this before?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I know I'm late, but I was able to figure this out.  Apparently in IE just setting the value of the underlying text field wont actually update the value in the datepicker, you have to set the value yourself.

For example:

```
$('#startdate').datepicker('setDate', start);
```